# Is it bad practice to include .exe files in a Nuget package?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nexus

First of all, I would like to clarify that I'm coming from a Java/Maven background.

I am managing Nexus and we have a team that are developing in .NET who are asking whether they can store `exe` files in Nexus under a Nuget repository. As this is not possible (and `exe`-s are not really artifacts as in "archives"), are Nuget packages a reasonable place to store `exe`-s? I would personally say "no", as, in my opinion, Nuget packages are supposed to just contain libraries and other resources, but as I'm not a .NET developer myself, I'd like to find out what the best practices are.

Comment: I am not quite clear about your use case, but it seems there are some packages that provide runnable tools (i.e. probably `.exe` files). For instance, [`NUnit.ConsoleRunner`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit.ConsoleRunner/) appears to be such a package.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> are Nuget packages a reasonable place to store exe-s?

If it's a tool, then **yes**. There are several good examples where Nuget is an excellent place to store exe-files.

*For example:*

The nuget package [dotless](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotless/) has a tool (standalone exe), which is a compiler for CSS-files. This enables us to use that tool in our (TFS-) build server without installing any third party software on the build server.

But other than that, I agree with you. A Nuget-package is mainly for libraries and other resources that will be references in the project. But it's after all just a platform for spreading code between developers and different teams.

Or as [Nuget](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/creating-a-package) puts it:

> No matter what your package does or what code it contains, NuGet is
>   how you package that functionality into a component that can be shared
>   with and used by any number of other developers.

Answer (score 2):

If the purpose of your nuget package is to deploy an executable program, then sure you can store an exe in there - what other option is there after all!

Comment: There's literally every other option.

Comment: @Abion47 such as. I'm talking in relation to the sentence `I am managing Nexus and we have a team that are developing in .NET who are asking whether they can store exe files in Nexus under a Nuget repository.`. Or, to put it another way, how else do you store an exe in a nuget repo without it being in a nuget package?